# How to create 2 tagging systems in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create 2 different tagging models

-One for 'Places'

-One for 'Topics'

I have a question and answers model similar to that of Stackoverflow.

The Question scaffold has a :title and :description at present.

The 2 tagging models will be added to a question. So the question will now have :title, :description, :place, :topics

These 2 new fields will have autocomplete abilities through jquery.

The places list will be just pulling from the db and the user cannot add a new place.

But, the user is allowed to add new topics if there is no topic in the db with that name.

Every Topic will have its own page with all the questions that have been tagged with the topic.

Every place will have its own page with all the questions that have been tagged to that place.

This is sort of an open ended question. I'm not looking for exact code, but more of a point in the right direction.

Can acts_as_taggable_on achieve this? I think it will only let you create 1 type.

I am really not sure how to create this. If someone could come up with a solution it would be a great help.

I think I have given all the info needed.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_taggable_on will solve your problem.

Firstly don't add seperate model for tagging.

As you can see in readme of https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

```
class Qestions < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :places, :topics
end
```

to add places tag use multiselect like select2() http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
and for topics use tag manager http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager.

Comment: Hi Anil, Thanks for your response. I see this could work. However, I just had a thought. Would it not be better to generate a migration e.g. addtopicstoquestions and then add it to the question? Same goes for places?